# Is setting session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor equal to 100% a bad idea?

Tags: php, session, symfony, cookies, garbage-collection

**The scenario:**

- User logs in
- Cookie is set to length of session
- After 1 hour of inactivity I wish to log out the user

**How I think I can solve this:**

- Set the session.gc_maxlifetime to 1 hour (3600)
- Set the session.gc_probability to 1
- Set the session.gc_divisor to 1
- Therefore having a 100% certainty that garbage collection will occur on any idle session cookies after 1 hour.

**My question:**

All the posts and documentation I've read has never mentioned setting a gc change of 100%, therefore is it bad to do this? Is there a better way?

It's a symfony app, and long term I would like to do something like this http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#session-meta-data but for now I was hoping to just do something simple with session.gc_*

One post I read implies that having a 100% garbage collection chance is "cost-intensive" [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes/1270960#1270960) is this true? If so, *how* cost intensive?

Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

The `gc_probability` and `gc_divisor` are there to let you define the "probability" of firing up the garbage collection (GC).

Since GC (as everything) comes with a cost, you wouldn't usually want it to run on each and every web request processed by your server - that would mean that every page opening or every AJAX request served from PHP would cause the GC to run.

So, depending on the actual server load and usage, the admin is expected to do an educated guess on how often should GC be run: once in 100, 1/10000 or 1 in million requests.

But, there's a problematic flaw in the OP's original reasoning - `that garbage collection will occur on any idle session`. The way I read the [manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability), the garbage collection will occur on ANY session, not just idle ones:

> `session.gc_maxlifetime integer`: *specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and **potentially** cleaned up*.

So, the session (idle or not) lifetime is decided with `gc_maxlifetime`, while the moment of the GC being started (as said in the docs: "potentially") is really decided with `gc_probability` and `gc_divisor`.

To resume, my late answer to the question would be - I would not under normal condition have GC running at each and every request (the 1/1 scenario you mentioned), because

1. that seems like a serious overkill. On some level, you would probably end up with thousands (if not worse) of IFs and only once going into its THEN
2. you would log out ANY user on your system after 60mins, not just the idle ones.

Comment: "you would log out ANY user on your system after 60mins, not just the idle ones " Wait, what?

Comment: Let's say your probability is 1/1000.  You may have 1000 hits daily, hourly, or in a minute. So, depending on the website load, your GC would fire up maybe once per day or each hour or each minute. Whenever it runs - it will kill all sessions older than 60mins (because `gc_maxlifetime` is not about only the **idle** sessions, but all the session).

Comment: I believe that as long as the user is still active and periodically runs the script that accesses the session, the user has another `gc_maxlifetime` seconds. In other words, the user has to *not* have accessed the session for `gc_maxlifetime` seconds to have their session cleaned up if the garbage collector is run. On my Windows desktop every time I run the script both the session file's *last modified* and *accessed* attributes are updated. The garbage collector does not care about the *created* date and time.

Comment: Tnx for the addition, @Booboo. If you tested it and it behaves as you say (considering the last accessed time), then you seem to have it right. The docs don't mention what is considered by "the number of seconds" - created or updated time.

Answer (score 0):

There are much better ways of doing this.

If this isn't for something particularly secure, you can [set an expiration date/length for the session cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) on the client-side. A technically minded user could tweak the expiration in this case, so you wouldn't want to use this on a bank site.

If you need something more secure, just store an expiration time along with the other session data and check against it. If it's exceeded, destroy their session and force them to log back in.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Yep there are better ways of doing this I'm sure, the way of doing it in Symfony with the link I supplied is my preferred approach. However, I'm interested in knowing more about session.gc_* stuff in general and if indeed it can be used to do something like what I was describing.